# Launch Minecraft 1.8.3 with C#

Tags: c#, minecraft, launcher

I'm currently trying to make a minecraft launcher for my server. But some reason it wont start. This is the code I used. Can someone check what I did wrong ?

```
string installPath = GetJavaInstallationPath();
string filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(installPath, "bin\\Javaw.exe");

Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("APPDATA", "C:\\SCO\\");

Process process = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
string dir = @"C:\SCO\.minecraft\versions\";
info.FileName = filePath;
info.CreateNoWindow = true;
info.Arguments = "-cp \"" + dir + "1.8.3.jar;" + dir + "lwjgl.jar;" + dir + "lwjgl_util.jar;" + dir + "jinput.jar;\" ";
info.Arguments += "\"-Djava.library.path=" + dir + "natives\" -Xmx1024M -Xms512M net.minecraft.client.main.Main " + username + " " + session;
process.StartInfo = info;
process.Start();
```

Comment: You're missing a bunch of libraries and arguments for the game.  You should look at the version JSONs (for instance, `%APPDATA%\.minecraft\versions\1.8.3\1.8.3.json`) for more info on what the argument structure and library list is (ideally, you should generate your library list and arguments from the version JSON; then you can launch _all_ versions).

Answer (score 3):

try this code, it worked for me

```
private void StartMinecraft(string username, string accessToken, string uuid, string gameVersion)
    {
        ProcessStartInfo minecraft = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = GetJavaInstallationPath() + @"\bin\javaw.exe",
            CreateNoWindow = false,
            Arguments = " -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:-UseAdaptiveSizePolicy -XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled -XX:+ParallelRefProcEnabled -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -Xmx1024M -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -XX:HeapDumpPath=MojangTricksIntelDriversForPerformance_javaw.exe_minecraft.exe.heapdump -Xss1M -Djava.library.path=C:/Users/" + Environment.UserName + "/AppData/Roaming/.minecraft/versions/" + gameVersion + "/natives -Dminecraft.launcher.brand=java-minecraft-launcher -Dminecraft.launcher.version=1.6.84-j -cp C:/Users/" + Environment.UserName + "/AppData/Roaming/.minecraft/libraries/oshi-project/oshi-core/1.1/oshi-core-1.1.jar;C:/Users/" + Environment.UserName + "/AppData/Roaming/.minecraft/libraries/net/java/dev/jna/jna/4.4.0/jna-4.4.0.jar;C:/Users/" + Environment.UserName + "/AppData/Roaming/.minecraft/libraries/net/java/dev/jna/platform/3.4.0/platform-3.4.0.jar;C:/Users/" + Environment.UserName + "/AppData/Roaming/.minecraft/libraries/com/ibm/icu/icu4j/66.1/icu4j-66.1.jar;C:/Users/" + Environment.UserName + "/AppData/Roaming/.minecraft/libraries/com/mojang/javabridge/1.0.22/javabridge-1.0.22.jar;C:/Users/" + Environment.UserName + "/AppData/Roaming/.minecraft/libraries/net/sf/jopt-simple/jopt-simple/5.0.3/jopt-simple-5.0.3.jar;C:/Users/" + Environment.UserName + "/AppData/Roaming/.minecraft/libraries/io/netty/netty-all/4.1.25.Final/netty-all-4.1.25.Final.jar;C:/Users/" + Environment.UserName + "/AppData/Roaming/.minecraft/libraries/com/google/guava/guava/21.0/guava-21.0.jar;C:/Users/" + Environment.UserName + "/AppData/Roaming/.minecraft/libraries/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.5/commons-lang3-3.5.jar;C:/Users/" + Environment.UserName + "/AppData/Roaming/.minecraft/libraries/commons-io/commons-io/2.5/commons-io-2.5.jar;C:/Users/" + Environment.UserName + "/AppData/Roaming/.minecraft/libraries/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.10/commons-codec-1.10.jar;C:/Users/" + Environment.UserName + "/AppData/Roaming/.minecraft/libraries/net/java/jinput/jinput/2.0.5/jinput-2.0.5.jar;C:/Users/" + Environment.UserName + "/AppData/Roaming/.minecraft/libraries/net/java/jutils/jutils/1.0.0/jutils-1.0.0.jar;C:/Users/" + Environment.UserName + "/AppData/Roaming/.minecraft/libraries/com/mojang/brigadier/1.0.17/brigadier-1.0.17.jar;C:/Users/" + Environment.UserName + "/AppData/Roaming/.minecraft/libraries/com/mojang/datafixerupper/4.0.26/datafixerupper-4.0.26.jar;C:/Users/" + Environment.UserName + "/AppData/Roaming/.minecraft/libraries/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.8.0/gson-2.8.0.jar;C:/Users/" + Environment.UserName + "/AppData/Roaming/.minecraft/libraries/org/apache/commons/commons-compress/1.8.1/commons-compress-1.8.1.jar;C:/Users/" + Environment.UserName + "/AppData/Roaming/.minecraft/libraries/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.3.3/httpclient-4.3.3.jar;C:/Users/" + Environment.UserName + "/AppData/Roaming/.minecraft/libraries/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.3/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar;C:/Users/" + Environment.UserName + "/AppData/Roaming/.minecraft/libraries/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.3.2/httpcore-4.3.2.jar;C:/Users/" + Environment.UserName + "/AppData/Roaming/.minecraft/libraries/it/unimi/dsi/fastutil/8.2.1/fastutil-8.2.1.jar;C:/Users/" + Environment.UserName + "/AppData/Roaming/.minecraft/libraries/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-api/2.8.1/log4j-api-2.8.1.jar;C:/Users/" + Environment.UserName + "/AppData/Roaming/.minecraft/libraries/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-core/2.8.1/log4j-core-2.8.1.jar;C:/Users/" + Environment.UserName + "/AppData/Roaming/.minecraft/libraries/org/lwjgl/lwjgl/3.2.2/lwjgl-3.2.2.jar;C:/Users/" + Environment.UserName + "/AppData/Roaming/.minecraft/libraries/org/lwjgl/lwjgl-jemalloc/3.2.2/lwjgl-jemalloc-3.2.2.jar;C:/Users/" + Environment.UserName + "/AppData/Roaming/.minecraft/libraries/org/lwjgl/lwjgl-openal/3.2.2/lwjgl-openal-3.2.2.jar;C:/Users/" + Environment.UserName + "/AppData/Roaming/.minecraft/libraries/org/lwjgl/lwjgl-opengl/3.2.2/lwjgl-opengl-3.2.2.jar;C:/Users/" + Environment.UserName + "/AppData/Roaming/.minecraft/libraries/org/lwjgl/lwjgl-glfw/3.2.2/lwjgl-glfw-3.2.2.jar;C:/Users/" + Environment.UserName + "/AppData/Roaming/.minecraft/libraries/org/lwjgl/lwjgl-stb/3.2.2/lwjgl-stb-3.2.2.jar;C:/Users/" + Environment.UserName + "/AppData/Roaming/.minecraft/libraries/org/lwjgl/lwjgl-tinyfd/3.2.2/lwjgl-tinyfd-3.2.2.jar;C:/Users/" + Environment.UserName + "/AppData/Roaming/.minecraft/libraries/com/mojang/text2speech/1.11.3/text2speech-1.11.3.jar;C:/Users/" + Environment.UserName + "/AppData/Roaming/.minecraft/libraries/by/ely/authlib/2.0.27.4/authlib-2.0.27.4.jar;C:/Users/" + Environment.UserName + "/AppData/Roaming/.minecraft/versions/" + gameVersion + "/" + gameVersion + ".jar net.minecraft.client.main.Main --username " + username + " --version " + gameVersion + " --gameDir C:/Users/" + Environment.UserName + "/AppData/Roaming/.minecraft --assetsDir C:/Users/" + Environment.UserName + "/AppData/Roaming/.minecraft/assets --assetIndex " + gameVersion + " --uuid " + uuid + " --accessToken " + accessToken + " --userType legacy --versionType release --width 925 --height 530"
        };
        Process.Start(minecraft);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Must try this: info.CreateNoWindow = true; to info.CreateNoWindow = false;

or recheck parameters and must be Java path is valid

Comment: I checked the java path and the parameters are correct. changing CreateNoWindow also didnt fixed the problem. do you have any more solutions ?

Comment: Can you tell me what the details error(or log or message)?

Comment: i couldnt find anything. the program doesnt crash it just does nothing.